# PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value but the value was set via ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a new record in my `Categories` table using `ActiveRecords`

Here is my `ActiveRecords` class:

```
require_relative '../../database/contract'
require 'active_record'

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = Tables::CATEGORIES

  def initialize(name)
    @active = true
    @name = name
    super()
  end

end
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
category = Category.new('jewelery')
category.save
```

It fails with error:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (089edda6-6b47-44b5-a612-0ab49987a99c, t, null). : INSERT INTO "categories" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

It looks like those instance variables are ignored, and the default values are set. Name column has no default value, but its `NOT NULL`.
Why aren't the variables set?

Comment: Please try `self.name = name` instead.

Comment: This only gives: undefined method `name=' for #<Category not initialized>

Comment: When overriding `ActiveRecord`'s constructor is not recommended, you might try - `super(active: true, name: name)`.

Comment: Can you make it an answer? It works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it it not recommended to override default `ActiveRecord::Base`'s constructor, it accepts a hash of attributes to be set for the object, thus you can do something like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = Tables::CATEGORIES

  def initialize(name)
    super({ active: true, name: name })
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = Tables::CATEGORIES
  after_initialize :init

  def init(name)
    self.name  = name             
  end
end
```